# changing button active status after clicking

Tags: python, button, tkinter

my python tkinter GUI has two classes. mainClass and subClass. subClass is compositing from mainClass to make the GUI. There are two buttons. start and stop buttons. normal state of start button is enabled and state of stop button is disabled. stop button status should change to enabled state when i press the start button and start button status should go to disable state to avoid multiple clicking. An suggestions?

```
class mainClass:
    def __init__(self, master, queue,  startCommand, stopCommand, guiClient)
        self.guiClient= guiClient

        btn_start = tkinter.Button(master, text='Start', command=self.guiClient.startCommand)
        btn_start .place(x=500, y=300)

        btn_stop = tkinter.Button(master, text='Stop',state=tkinter.DISABLED, command=self.guiClient.stopCommand)
        btn_stop .place(x=500, y=400)
#---rest of the codes----


subClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.myGui = mainClass(master, self.queue, self.startCommand, self.stopCommand, guiClient=self)
#---rest of __init__ here

# i tried following functions. got error when pressed start button.
# error was mainClass' object has no attribute 'btn_start

    def startCommand(self):

        self.myGui.btn_stop .config(state="normal")
        self.myGui.btn_start .config(state="disabled")

    def stopCommand(self):
        self.myGui.btn_stop .config(state="disabled")
        self.myGui.btn_start .config(state="normal")
```

Comment: Rename those buttons in MainClass to `self.btn_start`, respectively `self.btn_stop`.

Comment: you use wrong names in `startCommand/stopCommand` - it should be `self.myGui.start` `self.myGui.stop`. Or rename buttons in `mainClass`

Comment: ah.. so simple. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is telling you exactly what the problem is. It says that mainClass object has no attribute btn_start, which is true. That class has a *local* variable named `btn_start`, but no attribute.

You need to save the widget as a class attribute, then your code will work:

```
self.btn_start = tkinter.Button(...)
...
self.btn_stop = tkinter.Button(...)
```

With that, this will work:

```
def startCommand(self):

    self.myGui.btn_stop .config(state="normal")
    self.myGui.btn_start .config(state="disabled")
```

Answer (score -1):

To disable a button you can use

```py
btn_start['state'] = 'disabled'
```

or

```py
btn_start.config(state="disabled")
```

You can use it by a function.
Example:

```py
btn_start = tkinter.Button(master, text='Start', command=btn_start_onclick)
...
def btn_start_onclick():
    btn_start.config(state="disabled")
    self.guiClient.startCommand()
```

Sorry, i just saw you get an error.
You can define your button before the init.

```py
class mainClass:
    btn_start = None
    ...
    self.btn_start = tkinter.Button(master, text='Start', command=btn_start_onclick)
```

I wish it would work.